# How can I view flash content in Dolphin?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, dolphin-browser

I have a Chinese tablet, so I cannot install apps from Android Market (at least directly).

How can I see flv, swf and other kind of flash data using Dolphin web browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try side-loading a Flash Player apk file. There are a whole lot of them floating around on XDA, such as [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1288287) which has a download for Flash 11. Whether or not it works will also depend on other factors, such as the version of Android on the device and the processor it has (Flash requires an ARMv7 processor and Android 2.2 or later).